# How to apply codeigniter's URL_TITLE value to the URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I'm completely new to ci,

I have a url something like this:

```
http://localhost/mvc/post/prod_id/1
```

And I want it to be:

```
http://localhost/mvc/post/my-best-product
```

So far I'm able to manage to route all that to `home/post/` and learned the `segment` function also.

But my question is how do I really get the `url_title` out to the actual url.

I couldn't find any information on this particular subject. All I could find is how to use the `url_title` and how to route in ci. But they don't explain how we can actually change the base url name.

Please guide me to the right direction.

**solution Example:**

```
public function my_method($product_slug)
{
    $product1 = "training-for-recruitment";
    $product2 = "training-for-od";

    if($product_slug==$product1)
    {
        $this->load->view('prod1');

    }else if($product_slug==$product2)
    {
        $this->load->view('prod2');

    }else{
        show_404();
    }
}
```

This is not what exactly I'm going to do. It is just for others to understand the workaround of Slugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a unique slug for each of your product. Add a field for it on product table and every time, while selecting a product from table, use that slug instead of getting the product from primary id.

So, your function becomes like:

```
function product($product_slug)
{
    //get product by slug from database
    //load view page
}
```

Now, in **config/routes.php**

```
$route['your_controller_name/(:any)'] = "your_controller_name/product/$1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

1. Set up some logic that translates "my-best-product" to "1"
2. Set up routing in CI that calls your 'prod_id' controller and passes the URI vars